# Model tuning with Cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameters

I have a model tuning object that fits multiple models and tunes each one of them to find the best hyperparameter combination for each of the models. I want to perform cross-validation on the model tuning part and this is where I am facing a dilemma.

Let's assume that I am fitting just the one model- a random forest classifier and performing a 5 fold cross-validation. Currently, for the first fold that I leave out, I fit the random forest model and perform the model tuning. I am performing model tuning using the dlib package. I calculate the evaluation metric(accuracy, precision, etc) and select the best hyper-parameter combination.

Now when I am leaving out the second fold, should I be tuning the model again? Because if I do, I will get a different combination of hyperparameters than I did in the first case. If I do this across the five folds, what combination do I select?

The cross validators present in spark and sklearn use grid search so for each fold they have the same hyper-parameter combination and don't have to bother about hyper-parameter combinations changing across folds

Choosing the best hyper-parameter combination that I get when I leave out the first fold and using it for the subsequent folds doesn't sound right because then my entire model tuning is dependent on which fold got left out first. However, if I am getting different hyperparameters each time, which one do I settle on?

**TLDR:**

If you are performing let's say a derivative based model tuning along with cross-validation, your hyper-parameter combination changes as you iterate over folds. How do you select the best combination then? Generally speaking, how do you use cross-validation with derivative-based model tuning methods.

**PS:** Please let me know if you need more details

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a comment, but it is too long for this, so I post it as an answer instead.

Cross-validation and hyperparameter tuning are two separate things. Cross Validation is done to get a sense of the out-of-sample prediction error of the model. You can do this by having a dedicated validation set, but this raises the question if you are overfitting to this particular validation data. As a consequence, we often use cross-validation where the data are split in to `k` folds and each fold is used once for validation while the others are used for fitting. After you have done this for each fold, you combine the prediction errors into a single metric (e.g. by averaging the error from each fold). This then tells you something about the expected performance on unseen data, for a given set of hyperparameters.

Once you have this single metric, you can change your hyperparameter, repeat, and see if you get a lower error with the new hyperparameter. This is the hpyerparameter tuning part. The CV part is just about getting a good estimate of the model performance for the given set of hyperparameters, i.e. you do not change hyperparameters 'between' folds.

I think one source of confusion might be the distinction between hyperparameters and parameters (sometimes also referred to as 'weights', 'feature importances', 'coefficients', etc). If you use a gradient-based optimization approach, these change between iterations until convergence or a stopping rule is reached. This is however different from hyperparameter search (e.g. how many trees to plant in the random forest?).

By the way, I think questions like these should better be posted to the Cross-Validated or Data Science section here on StackOverflow.